# windows 7 64 bit installation on ssd crucial 300c can't install

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, ssd

I have a small problem.

Today my Crucial c300 arrived. Now I want a clean install windows 7 64 bit. After firing up the dvd, I get a screen which says that it needs drivers for my hardware. Why cant I install?

I have the following specs

Biostar i55 motherboard
sata 1 - Crucial 3ooc
sata 2 - CD/DVD drive

Processor Intel i860

I tried the following, pff where shall I begin

bios settings:

sata -> ACHI
sata -> IDE
sata -> RAID0

Downloaded the ACHI/RAID drivers from the website of Biostar for my motheboard and copied it on a usb device, and pointed the browser of the windows 7 installation guide to a compatible driver, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy of the windows 7 version I used was badly burned, I burned a new one on 22 KBPS and I could install Windows 7 64 bit without a problem. Same ISO.

Comment: just a thought - you might want to consider deleting the question...

Comment: Maybe this answer could be relevant to other people. I think it's best to let it be. I have spend 3 hours try and die, till i read something about a badly burned disk. I tried the same iso again, this time I used winiso to burn a new copy. No problems with installing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your BIOS settings might be wrong. If there is a RAID0 I would usually just set the ACHI sata to RAID = depending on your mother board. However there might be a problem of the Motherboard with the new hard disk you just bought. I would suggest you upgrade the motherboard firmware and BIOS version too.

Answer (score 0):

I used novicorps wintoflash  free program to install windows 7 64bit  from the installation disk to my usb drive. Boots right up and loads right to the ssd drive fast!